# ROS2 add_on_set_parameters_callback not triggered for launch parameter

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've defined a callback for parameter value change:

```
MyNode::MyNode() : Node("myNode")
{
  // subscriber, publisher, ....

  // Define callback to update parameter
  parameter_set_callback = this->add_on_set_parameters_callback(std::bind(&MyNode::update_parameter_callback, this, _1));
}
```

The function `update_parameter_callback` itself sets the changed parameter values in my application.

```
rcl_interfaces::msg::SetParametersResult MyNode::update_parameter_callback(const std::vector<rclcpp::Parameter> &parameters)
{

  rcl_interfaces::msg::SetParametersResult res;

  // Update parameter
  res = UpdateParameter_MyCode(parameters);

  return res;
}
```

This works well when setting parameter during runtime via `ros2 param set`

When I set a default value in launch file, this callback is not triggered:

```
<node pkg = "my_pkg" name = "MyNode" exec = "MyNode" >
    <param name="bar" value="201.0"/>
</node>
```

Is there any chance to re-use existing callback for parameter that are set within launch?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/416966/ros2-add_on_set_parameters_callback-not-triggered-for-launch-parameter/) by [holunder](https://answers.ros.org/users/64636/holunder/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2023-06-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems like changing the order in my code fixed the issue.

When I set`add_on_set_parameters_callback` before actually declaring parameter, it ensures that parameter override value is triggering the callback and then populating the value to my function.

---

Originally posted by [holunder](https://answers.ros.org/users/64636/holunder/) with karma: 20 on 2023-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [holunder](https://answers.ros.org/users/64636/holunder/) on 2023-06-29**:
if someone with higher reputation could mark this reply as an answer, the questions could be closed properly.